# Problem in the text tag getting the same value

Tags: docusignapi

I have 2 **radio** tags, when selecting the answer "yes" the text tag appears. The problem is when I type any text in any of the two **text** fields, they are repeated, example: if I type "ok" in the first text field the second is automatically pre-filled with the value "ok" too, if I change the second text, the first is also changed automatically with the same value.
The two text fields are different in the database.

Print : https://ibb.co/MkTnkxY

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature! To stop it, change the `Data Label` for one of the text fields so they no longer match each other.